# NetworkManager no longer auto-connects on login

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

I've [configured `nm-applet` to run during X login](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/75facaae98d4a1a9fd5942171f7307695e2b8448/.xinitrc#L58), and I've connected to my home Wi-Fi network many times. Recently it no longer tries to connect to the network after logging in. In the connection's "General" tab "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" is checked:

[image]

The wired network connection is also configured to connect automatically, but it's not been connected for weeks. It and the Wi-Fi are the only configured connections.

NM *does* try to reconnect if I disable and re-enable Wi-Fi after connecting, so at some level I guess it still knows about the auto-connect (or maybe it's just trying to get to the previous state).

When I re-enabled Wi-Fi just a few minutes ago it created a *new* connection with the same name as the existing Wi-Fi connection with a "-1" at the end. After deleting that connection I can no longer reproduce this behaviour.

The SSID is not hidden. I just booted, NM auto-connected after login and created another copy of the connection:

```
$ nmcli c
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        6c870845-d2c0-465a-9f74-ae53ecd6ac0c   802-3-ethernet    Mon 21 Apr 2014 08:23:52 AM BST   
BTHub4-GRK6               77cfadf5-e580-411a-978b-3c1d44265373   802-11-wireless   Mon 21 Apr 2014 08:28:52 AM BST   
BTHub4-GRK6 1             858e53cc-000b-461f-b2c1-7ce3e761a833   802-11-wireless   never
```

NetworkManager is already running:

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2014-05-22 08:13:30 BST; 12h ago
 Main PID: 340 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─340 /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           └─875 /usr/bin/dhcpcd -B -K -L -G -c /usr/lib/networkmanager/nm-dhcp-client.action wl...
```

Comment: I have the same issue w/ it on my Fedora 19 laptop. It occurs when I go to work I often have to manually connect, but at home it always auto connects.

Comment: None of the SSID's are hidden by chance? http://blog.nixpanic.net/2011/01/connect-automatically-and-immediately.html

Comment: Also out of curiosity can you confirm that the network shows "Auto" in the `NAME` column when you run `nmcli c`? My network though setup to auto connect does not show "Auto" here. All my other networks that do work w/ auto connecting do however show "Auto".

Comment: Just a note, `nm-applet` is not there to autoconnect or anything like that, this is handled by NetworkManager which on the other hand doesn't care so much about login sessions. Which version of NetworkManager are you using? Which type of wireless authentication is used?

Comment: @slm I suspect that's been abandoned (or perhaps a distro-specific feature). I certainly never turned off the auto-connection.

Answer (score -1):

Have you enabled the NetworkManager systemd service?

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
```